# Error: RMAN-06172- Failed to recover oracle DB from RMAN backup files of another oracle DB

Tags: oracle, rman

I'm trying to recover oracle DB (v11.2) in ubuntu server using rman backup that is taken from the  database in the old host but failed with error: RMAN-06172: no AUTOBACKUP found or specified handle is not a valid copy or piece.

**The RMAN backup has been taken from the database in the old host using below steps:**

```
run 
{
 backup spfile include current controlfile format '/mydir/control-%U';
 allocate channel d1 type disk format '/mydir/RMAN_full_%U.bkp';
 backup as compressed backupset database plus archivelog;
 CROSSCHECK BACKUP;
 release channel d1;
}
```

In the new host, Oracle DB (v11.2) has been started and we need recover data of the old one using the backup files created.

1. The backup created in the old host has been copied to new host with suitable permission
2. Try to recover "controlfile" but failed.
3. Steps for restoring controlfile:

   ```
   sqlplus / as sysdba
   shutdown immediate;
   exit;

   rman target / 
   startup nomount;
   restore controlfile from '/home/oracle/control-ja23htj0_1_1';
   ```
4. restore command output:

   ```
   RMAN> restore controlfile from '/home/oracle/control-ja23htj0_1_1';

     restore controlfile from '/home/oracle/control-ja23htj0_1_1';
     Starting restore at 14-AUG-23
     using channel ORA_DISK_1

     RMAN Command Id : 2023-08-14T22:16:32
     RMAN Command Id : 2023-08-14T22:16:32
     RMAN-00571: 
     ===========================================================
     RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS 
     ===============
     RMAN-00571: 
     ===========================================================
     RMAN-03002: failure of restore command at 08/14/2023 22:25:33
     RMAN-06172: no AUTOBACKUP found or specified handle is not a valid copy or piece
   ```
5. File permission:

   ```
   bash-4.4$ ls -alrth /home/oracle/control-ja23htj0_1_1

         -rwxr-xr-x 1 oracle oinstall 16M Aug 14 21:31 /home/oracle/dbdfrz1/control-ja23htj0_1_1
   ```

**RMAN configuration parameters:**

```
RMAN> show all;
show all;
using target database control file instead of recovery catalog
RMAN configuration parameters for database with db_unique_name FREE are:
CONFIGURE RETENTION POLICY TO REDUNDANCY 1; # default
CONFIGURE BACKUP OPTIMIZATION OFF; # default
CONFIGURE DEFAULT DEVICE TYPE TO DISK; # default
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP ON; # default
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO '%F'; # default
CONFIGURE DEVICE TYPE DISK PARALLELISM 1 BACKUP TYPE TO BACKUPSET; # default
CONFIGURE DATAFILE BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1; # default
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1; # default
CONFIGURE MAXSETSIZE TO UNLIMITED; # default
CONFIGURE ENCRYPTION FOR DATABASE OFF; # default
CONFIGURE ENCRYPTION ALGORITHM 'AES256'; # default
CONFIGURE COMPRESSION ALGORITHM 'BASIC' AS OF RELEASE 'DEFAULT' OPTIMIZE FOR LOAD TRUE ; # default
CONFIGURE RMAN OUTPUT TO KEEP FOR 7 DAYS; # default
```

Comment: Oracle is not certified to run on Ubuntu server, and there is no guarantee that any utilities like RMAN will work as expected. The backup files themselves could be corrupted, or the utilities or database insurance may not read or process them correctly.

Comment: I've tried to run same recovery steps in docker container with free image provided by oracle and faced same issue "docker run -it --rm -w /home/oracle/dbdfrz1 -v ~/dbdfrz1:/home/oracle/dbdfrz1 container-registry.oracle.com/database/free bash".  However, I,ve tried to start container and take DB backup from it and remove container and then start new one and restore it from the backup, it worked fine.  So, Could you please mention if there’s any way to confirm that the backup files are corrupted?

Comment: Do you have copies of spfile and controlfile in FRA, then you might start with using something like `restore spfile from autobackup db_recovery_file_dest=’/myfradir/%F’ db_name=proddb;`

Comment: @Barbaros, I need to restore from backup file that is taken using rman backup commands from another database not the Autobackup files.

Do you mean to copy the controlfile backup to FRA and try to restore from it there?